# Maintain reference then assign new object thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a static int array that is shared among threads:

```
static int[] res = new int[10];
```

In a function, I want to isolate what is in res and basically, reset its values to 0. Is the following code thread-safe?

```
final int[] copy = res;
res = new int[10];
// do sth with `copy`
```

If not, what could be a smarter way to do without hurting performance (other than using AtomicInteger or Semaphore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not thread-safe. There is no guarantee when, if ever, other Threads will see the change to the static variable `res`.

You could change it to:

```
static volatile int[] res = new int[10];
```

And then other threads will be guaranteed to pick it up the next time the use the `res` variable.

In this particular case where you are only resetting to zero and have no dependency on the previous value of `res`, this is probably good enough.

In cases where you do depend on the previous value (or other shared variables) you'll need to implement further synchronization between threads.

However one warning: other threads may still be manipulating values in your "`copy`" variable as they may have retrieved the reference and held on to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not safe without some form of synchronization.

Is it possible for one thread to do the reference swap that is shown in your example while some other thread is updating the array? If so, then that code is *very* not safe because different threads could disagree on which array `res` refers to, and updates could be lost as a result.

Even if the only thread that updates the array is the same one that does the swap, the code *still* is not safe because other threads could see updates to the array members happen out-of-order with respect to each other and, out-of-order with respect to the re-assignment of `res`.

You should protect *all* accesses (from *any* thread) to `res` and to the array members with a lock.